# CSS3: How to put contents in phone background

Tags: html, css

I have a div. in that div I have a center phone background image and in that phone background div I want to have contents.

just like in the image[image]

I want to have the contents in the phone in the black background div.

```css
body{
background:#f0f3f4;
}

.custom_app_phone_section_div .custom_app_phone_div {
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 1136px;
}
.custom_app_phone_section_div .custom_app_phone_div .custom_app_phone_bg_image_div {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/JtWe3vB.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 640px;
  height: 1136px;
}
.custom_app_phone_section_div .custom_app_phone_div .custom_app_phone_bg_image_div .custom_app_phone_contents_div {
  
  background:black;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_app_phone_section_div">
          <div class="custom_app_phone_div">
            <div class="custom_app_phone_bg_image_div">
              <div class="custom_app_phone_contents_div">
                contents div
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I want to put contents div in the phone.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use z-index for that phone div lesser than the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.custom_app_phone_section_div .custom_app_phone_div {
  margin: 5% auto 0 auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 1136px;
}
.custom_app_phone_section_div .custom_app_phone_div .custom_app_phone_bg_image_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/JtWe3vB.png") no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.custom_app_phone_section_div .custom_app_phone_div .custom_app_phone_bg_image_div .custom_app_phone_contents_div {
  position: relative;
  top: 7.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border: thin red solid;
  width: 43%;
  height: 43.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_app_phone_section_div">
          <div class="custom_app_phone_div">
            <div class="custom_app_phone_bg_image_div">
              <div class="custom_app_phone_contents_div">
                contents div
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Check this.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add another image on phone's image. and align it.